# What parts of the Vedas was Maharshi Bhrigu revealed to?

Tags: vedas, rishi, bhrigu

Most rishis have been revealed to a good chunk of the Vedas to be considered "Rishis".

I am wondering what sections in the Vedas got revealed to Maharshi Bhrigu.

All I can guess is maybe the Bhrigu Valli of the Taittiriya Upanishad since it contains a discourse with him.

Comment: Rishis did not compose the Vedas. Rishis heard the Vedas. Vedas don't have human authors.

Comment: So you can ask if Maharshi Bhrigu heard some Vedic mantras or not if yes which Suktas or Mantras were heard by him.

Comment: @Rickross, well compose means to order and arrange, not to create in my instance. Maharshi Bhrigu heard the Vedas and composed them together, if I am not mistaken. Please correct me if so. 

I'll change the question.